# Gmail Verification after Migration to Different Server

Tags: gmail

I am migrating a client from its current web host to my cloud server at Digital Ocean. Their email provider is Gmail. I have already added the MX records for Google, but my question is, do I need to do the TXT record verification again, or is that done only once for that domain?

Will my clients email work when I point the nameservers to Digital Ocean without doing the verification?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, as the dns tag explains: DNS QUESTIONS MUST BE PROGRAMMING RELATED. Use this tag for programming questions related to writing code that interacts with the Domain Name System (DNS); for example, writing code that uses gethostbyname()

Answer (score 0):

I migrated the site over to my server, and the clients email was not affected. As is my understanding, the first time you register your domain with your email, it must be verified with whatever service provider you use (Gmail, Zoho mail etc). Once that email domain is verified, it is linked, and doesn't have to be verified again.

As long as the new server has the proper MX records present, the email will work.

If anyone has more insight into this, feel free to respond.